# How to capture mandatory text field data with WooCommerce Product Add-ons?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm looking for a way to capture and display data entered into required text fields using the "WooCommerce Product Add-ons" plugin in WooCommerce. I have 100 products with custom text fields and I want to show this data on the custom thank you page after a purchase.

I've already created a custom field on my thank you page to display the data. However, I don't know how to extract this data from the purchased products text fields and pass it to the custom field on the thank you page.

I was wondering if anyone has experience with this plugin or knows how to get this data and make it available on the thank you page.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Here is a simplified example of my problem:

I have a WooCommerce product with a required text field called "Special Note" created with WooCommerce Product Add-ons.
A customer purchases this product and enters a special note in the text field during the purchase process.
After your purchase is complete, I would like to display this special note on my personalized thank you page.
I have already created a custom field on the thank you page to display the data. However, I don't know how to extract this data from the purchased product text field and pass it to the custom field on the thank you page.

I kindly ask for your help in understanding how to get this data from the text fields and make it available on the thank you page. Any suggestions or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding custom code to your theme's functions.php file.

You can use the woocommerce_thank you action to achieve this.

```
// Add this code to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin.

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'display_special_note_on_thankyou_page');
function display_special_note_on_thankyou_page($order_id) {
    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Iterate through the order items to find the product with the "Special Note" field
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        // Check if this item has the "Special Note" field
        if ($special_note = $item->get_meta('Special Note')) {
            // Display the special note on the thank you page
            echo '<p>Special Note: ' . esc_html($special_note) . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

On your custom thank you page, you'll need to retrieve the data stored in the order and display it. You can use a similar hook to modify the thank you page content. Here's an example:

```
function display_custom_data_on_thankyou_page($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    // Retrieve and display the custom data stored in the order.
}

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'display_custom_data_on_thankyou_page');
```